# How integrate image recognition to formFlow in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

```
[Serializable]
    public class MyAwaitableImage : AwaitableAttachment
    {
        // Mandatory: you should have this ctor as it is used by the recognizer
        public MyAwaitableImage(Attachment source) : base(source) { }

        // Mandatory: you should have this serialization ctor as well & call base
        protected MyAwaitableImage(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }

        // Optional: here you can check for content-type for ex 'image/png' or other..
        public override async Task<ValidateResult> ValidateAsync<T>(IField<T> field, T state)
        {
            var result = await base.ValidateAsync(field, state);

            if (result.IsValid)
            {
                var isValidForMe = this.Attachment.ContentType.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("image/png");

                if (!isValidForMe)
                {
                    result.IsValid = false;
                    result.Feedback = $"Hey, dude! Provide a proper 'image/png' attachment, not any file on your computer like '{this.Attachment.Name}'!";
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        // Optional: here you can provide additional or override custom help text completely..
        public override string ProvideHelp<T>(IField<T> field)
        {
            var help = base.ProvideHelp(field);

            help += $"{Environment.NewLine}- Only 'image/png' can be attached to this field.";

            return help;
        }

        // Optional: here you can define your custom logic to get the attachment data or add custom logic to check it, etc..
        protected override async Task<Stream> ResolveFromSourceAsync(Attachment source)
        {
            var result = await base.ResolveFromSourceAsync(source);

            // You can apply custom logic to result or avoid calling base and resolve it yourself
            // For ex. if you plan to use your instance several times you can return a MemoryStream instead

            return result;
        }
    }
// here is the form that the Bot takes to the user
    [Serializable]
    public class VehicleForm
    {
        [Prompt("What's your name?")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Prompt("Upload your image")]
        public MyAwaitableImage Image;
```

I am creating a form in bot framework, i want to implement the image recognition API and use it to validate the image uploaded by the user. If this image is not a person's image the bot will reject and ask the person for a valid image. Please i need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to implement the image recognition API and use it to validate the image uploaded by the user. If this image is not a person's image the bot will reject and ask the person for a valid image.

The Computer Vision API could help analyze image, you can perform image analysis in your validation method. The following sample code work for me, you can refer to it.

```
public override async Task<ValidateResult> ValidateAsync<T>(IField<T> field, T state)
{
    var result = await base.ValidateAsync(field, state);

    if (result.IsValid)
    {
        var isValidForMe = this.Attachment.ContentType.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("image/png");

        if (!isValidForMe)
        {
            result.IsValid = false;
            result.Feedback = $"Hey, dude! Provide a proper 'image/png' attachment, not any file on your computer like '{this.Attachment.Name}'!";
        }
        else
        {
            var url = this.Attachment.ContentUrl;

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            Stream filestrem = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
            httpClient.Dispose();

            byte[] ImageAsByteArray = null;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int count = 0;
                do
                {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    count = filestrem.Read(buf, 0, 1024);
                    ms.Write(buf, 0, count);
                } while (filestrem.CanRead && count > 0);
                ImageAsByteArray = ms.ToArray();
            }

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            // Request headers.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(
                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{Subscription_Key_here}");

            // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
            string requestParameters =
                "visualFeatures=Categories";

            // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
            string uri = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/analyze?" + requestParameters;

            HttpResponseMessage response;


            using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(ImageAsByteArray))
            {
                // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
                // The other content types you can use are "application/json"
                // and "multipart/form-data".
                content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                // Make the REST API call.
                response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
            }

            // Get the JSON response.
            string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var rs = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(contentString);


            if (rs.HasValues)
            {
                string val = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)rs).First).First).First).First).Value).Value.ToString();

                if (val!= "people_")
                {
                    result.IsValid = false;
                    result.Feedback = $"The image '{this.Attachment.Name}' is not a person's image!";
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

*Test result:*

[image]

**Note:**

*You can also check the following documentations to know how to use Computer Vision API/client library to analyze image.*

- [Quickstart: Analyze a local image with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-analyze)
- [Analyze both a local and a remote image to extract visual features using the Computer Vision Windows client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/csharp-analyze-sdk)

**Update:**

> Please i need the bot to be able to describe the image content ( description ) not just to validate.

You can include “Description” in querystring parameters to return the description of the image content. For more information, you can read ["Computer Vision API" documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa).

```
string requestParameters = "visualFeatures=Categories,Description";
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i really appreciate. Please i need the bot to be able to describe the image content ( description )  not just to validate. Please kindly assist. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @OluwatosinSamuelBabalola, I updated the reply, you can refer to it.

Comment: **Hello** @Fei Han please all i need to get out is the caption value in the JSON and display it to the user e.g`
      "captions": [
         {
            "text": "a close up of an empty city street at night",
            "confidence": 0.7965622853462756
         }
      ]` i have added Caption to the requestParameters string. I have tried but seem not to work. please kindly assist.

Comment: hello @FeiHan any more help for me ?

Comment: Hi @OluwatosinSamuelBabalola, you can try to use `var des = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue)rs["description"]["captions"][0]["text"]).Value;` to extract caption value, which work for me.

Comment: Hi @OluwatosinSamuelBabalola, Any updates? Are you able to extract caption value from the response now?

Comment: yes!. Thank you very much, i sincerely appreciate, you have really helped me a lot. I'm new to C# and i just started building with the bot framework. Thanks once again, God bless you!!!!.

Comment: Hello @FeiHan you have been very helpful understanding the bot framework architecture. Please can i contact you for help?